# Can connect to Samba, but access denied to homes

Tags: centos, samba

I can connect to the samba server using both IP address and server name, and I can see the home folder name, but can't connect to it

smb.cnf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Venus
    wins support = no
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 0777
    case sensitive = no
    dns proxy = no
    interfaces = 127.0.0.1/8 eth0
    bind interfaces only = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    security = user
    encrypt passwords = true
    passdb backend = smbpasswd
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    unix password sync = no
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    pam password change = no


[homes]
   comment = User Directories
   path = /data/localdevs/%u
   public = no
   browsable = yes
   writable = yes
```

the /etc/samba folder has the following files in it

```
lmhosts  smb.conf  smb.conf.orig  smbusers
```

The output of "sudo pdbedit -L" is

```
user1:500:
```

ls -abl /data/localdevs/

```
drwxr-xr-x. 4 user1 user1 4096 Jul 24 17:35 user1
```

These are what samba logs are showing when I get the access denied to user1's home directory

```
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599216,  3] smbd/process.c:1489(process_smb)
  Transaction 24 of length 90 (0 toread)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599350,  3] smbd/process.c:1298(switch_message)
  switch message SMBntcreateX (pid 2440) conn 0x7f6758780c00
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599373,  4] smbd/uid.c:257(change_to_user)
  change_to_user: Skipping user change - already user
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599412,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599485,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599508,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599552,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599581,  3] smbd/dosmode.c:166(unix_mode)
  unix_mode(.) returning 0766
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599643,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599668,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599707,  4] smbd/open.c:1990(open_file_ntcreate)
  calling open_file with flags=0x0 flags2=0x0 mode=0766, access_mask = 0x81, open_access_mask = 0x81
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599806,  3] smbd/open.c:467(open_file)
  Error opening file . (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED) (local_flags=0) (flags=0)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.599838,  3] smbd/error.c:80(error_packet_set)
  error packet at smbd/error.c(160) cmd=162 (SMBntcreateX) NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604075,  3] smbd/process.c:1489(process_smb)
  Transaction 25 of length 90 (0 toread)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604193,  3] smbd/process.c:1298(switch_message)
  switch message SMBntcreateX (pid 2440) conn 0x7f6758780c00
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604216,  4] smbd/uid.c:257(change_to_user)
  change_to_user: Skipping user change - already user
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604268,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604336,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604395,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604419,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604442,  3] smbd/dosmode.c:166(unix_mode)
  unix_mode(.) returning 0766
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604532,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604554,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604583,  4] smbd/open.c:1990(open_file_ntcreate)
  calling open_file with flags=0x0 flags2=0x0 mode=0766, access_mask = 0x81, open_access_mask = 0x81
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604679,  3] smbd/open.c:467(open_file)
  Error opening file . (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED) (local_flags=0) (flags=0)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.604705,  3] smbd/error.c:80(error_packet_set)
  error packet at smbd/error.c(160) cmd=162 (SMBntcreateX) NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.606977,  3] smbd/process.c:1489(process_smb)
  Transaction 26 of length 80 (0 toread)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607096,  3] smbd/process.c:1298(switch_message)
  switch message SMBtrans2 (pid 2440) conn 0x7f6758780c00
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607119,  4] smbd/uid.c:257(change_to_user)
  change_to_user: Skipping user change - already user
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607139,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5100(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 1004
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607162,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607184,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.607208,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5226(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo . (fnum = -1) level=1004 call=5 total_data=0
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608306,  3] smbd/process.c:1489(process_smb)
  Transaction 27 of length 80 (0 toread)
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608362,  3] smbd/process.c:1298(switch_message)
  switch message SMBtrans2 (pid 2440) conn 0x7f6758780c00
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608383,  4] smbd/uid.c:257(change_to_user)
  change_to_user: Skipping user change - already user
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608403,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5100(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 1005
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608439,  3] smbd/vfs.c:881(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name [.] [/data/localdevs/user1]
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608461,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1038(check_reduced_name)
  check_reduced_name: . reduced to /data/localdevs/user1
[2012/07/24 20:27:08.608484,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5226(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo . (fnum = -1) level=1005 call=5 total_data=0
```

Comment: How are you connecting? Via a Windows client, smbclient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was this

```
sudo chcon -t samba_share_t ./data/localdevs/user1
```

Apparently it's a centos thing.

Note: The syntax as root (replacing  with the directory you are trying to share)

```
chcon -t samba_share_t <share_folder>
```

Comment: CentOS uses SELinux to control user and application access to folders and files to add extra security. That's why you have to use `chcon` to change the security settings.

Comment: Argh!  This did indeed fix my problem as well.  Usually when you get "access denied" errors and SELinux is at fault, something gets put in the audit log... not so in this case!

Comment: Thanks, it resolves the issue. My SELinux is blocking the access to the folder. after issuing the below command it resolves the issue. chcon -t samba_share_t <share_folder> chcon is the utility -t is the switch samba_share_t is the keyword

Answer (score 1):

As user893730 implied in his answer, this is caused by SELinux. Importantly, as mentioned by Charles in a comment to the same answer, this might not show up in the audit log.

There is a boolean named `samba_enable_home_dirs` in the policy that controls whether Samba can share the home directories. Instead of re-labelling the directories with the `chcon` command, you can set that boolean with the following command:

```
sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
```

The `-P` option will make the change persistent across reboots.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and tried many of the posted solutions to no avail. That is until I found that selinux was enabled. After switching it from 'enforcing' to 'permissive'... presto I can read and write files from windows!